# Creating a launcher icon for sublime text 3 with the Exec=sublime_text instead of long path with shortcut icon retained in launcher

Tags: fedora, desktop-shortcuts, sublime-text

I created a shortcut for sublime text 3 (sublime_text.desktop)[The file with the good looking icon] and this happened,

[image: my shortcut location and my executable location]

[image: error message]

*The code i used in **sublime_text.desktop***

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=Sublime Text
Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
Icon=sublime-text
Exec=./sublime_text
Terminal=true
Categories=Development;IDE;
```

I've used many similar examples but didnt work(and yes double clicking sublime_text executable works).

Comment: Please try to write the error codes in your question. Some guys like me are not capable to browse in imgur.

Comment: there are no error codes :/ sorry

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this will work:

```
Exec=./sublime_text
```

Use full path instead.

```
Exec=/full/path/to/sublime_text
```

To make it work with ./sublime_text you need to have .desktop file and executable file in the same current working directory (.)

If yet does not open, then check for permission issues.
When you call the .desktop file with a double click or from your DE apps menu then the .desktop file is executed as user.
If the folder you have your executable file is a root folder, execution will fail due to missing priveleges.
Users can not run root progs, unless the permissions have been set to apply such operation (allow execution by others).

Comment: i specifically mentioned that i dont want to use full paths & without ./ it does not work either

Comment: @surajmandalcell What's wrong with full paths? In order to make ./ to work the .desktop file and the executable file it seems that must be in the same directory, but yet is not 100% sure that will work

Comment: it didnt :( sorry but i dont know what am i doing wrong

Comment: @surajmandalcell Check for permissions. If you call the .desktop file from a double click on your desktop or from your DE apps menu then the .desktop file is called as user. if the folder you have your executable is a root folder, will fail due to missing priveleges. Users can not run root progs, unless the permissions have been set to apply such operation.

Comment: it turns out that when i use "sudo nautilus" and launch my sublime_text.desktop then it works...and it does not work normally :( any help on permission issue??

Comment: Open nautilus with sudo, browse to the location of the executable , right click on executable, look for permissions tab, and apply execute to others. Maybe you need to do the same for the .desktop file.

Comment: aan....its already set to read and write for me

Comment: There is read, write and execute. Three different flags. Go with command line (as root) and type `ls -all sublime*`. You must be seeing x flags in all the groups.

Comment: 'ls -all sublime_text' shows the following output '-rwxrwxrwx 1 cruelplatypus67 cruelplatypus67 5200392 Sep 23 15:43 sublime_text'

Comment: @surajmandalcell OK, this is good - no permissions problem. What about the permissions of .desktop file?

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 cruelplatypus67 cruelplatypus67 231 Feb  7 20:40 sublime_text.desktop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53185/discussion-between-suraj-mandalcell-and-george-vasiliou).